# JSON or HTML: Which output can perform better?

Tags: html, ruby, json, performance

I am thinking of improving website performance by moving rendering to the client side. The current stack is: `(router, sphinx, db) + HTML`. I am thinking of changing this to: `(router, sphinx, db) + JSON`.

All of clients are running i7 processors and they don't care much about client side rendering performance. We also have client side app which is ready to connect to resful JSON API (this is not to go into discussion about client vs server side rendering).

1) Rendering on server takes about 20% of time (and 80% goes to routing, sphinx, db). I heard that outputting JSON takes about half of the time that it takes to output HTML, so I think it would be 10% improvement, and those 10% could go into data processing. Am I right about that?

2) I believe that 10% improvement for one server means that, to get the same amount of performance with a large scale app with 100 physical servers, we need 10% less servers: in this case 90 instead of 100. Is this correct?

3) How is it possible to get the best performance in Ruby to output JSON instead of any other format?

4) Taking daily scenarios, what difference could be made performance wise if we output JSON instead of HTML?

Answer (score 1):

1, 2) Probably yes, but there could be uncounted for factors, which may make the performance increase to be less than you expect. Like, if bottleneck is IO, and as HTML creation probably is CPU-limited, then reducing CPU load will only let CPUs idle more. Only way to find out really is to have reliable benchmarks while running parallel request handling, and get hard numbers.

Further, spending the hours to develop client-side rendering might be more expensive, than just paying for more server capacity... Moore's law is still holding, doing that kind of optimization for such a small improvement is probably not worth the development cost... Probably better to concentrate those dev resources on something which would increase revenue, instead of trying to make small savings.

3) JSON generation probably uses a native library, while HTML generation happens in Ruby script code. And native code is typically 1-2 orders of magnitude faster than interpreted (and not JIT-compiled) code at low level operations. The higher level operation it is, the narrower the gap, so if "generate JSON" is the high level operation, then it's equally fast if you call it from Ruby or from compiled language code.

4) Well, not sure I understand the question, but see answer 1,2...

Comment: In my experience develop client side app from the scratch is easier and faster than developing server side app, so having right team with right skill set would not make that a problem. Also about #3 still did not understand if native JSON lib is faster or Ruby script code?

Comment: @VytautasButkus About development cost, yes, it may or may not be a non-issue. If you can generate the JSON data with one call, then it does not matter if you generate HTML at server side or client side, but if you need same amount of code to generate JSON as HTML, then you need double the code if you have JSON generation at server side and HTML generation at client side. About Ruby vs. native, I update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

see http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/  maybe that will help you

best way to find out for you particular case is to implement it and test. 
you can use new relic and google analytics (maybe others as well) to see client performance and rendering times and experience

Comment: Thank you, but I already read everything in that page but still did not gather enough information and arguments for one or another. Also at this point I don't care about user experience all I car about is dropping server's load to the best possible minimum. So I need to know how much can I win by moving stuff to client side rendering.