# ASP.NET Web Api: Sending json vs html direclty from the api to return static list of cities from server to client

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js

I have api that returns citylist to me as json.

CityList looks something like: {1, "City1"}, {2, "City2"} and so on.
It is List and Class City has following properties: CityId, CityName.

I have to bind this city list on client side. So i am putting call to this api that returns me json response. I further use knockout to bind this json through an observable array. I have defined  that listens to changes in this observable array as we do to bind standard list through knockout observable arrays.

I was thinking instead of doing all this, would it be efficient if i bring direct html from api.

Pros:
 1. No knockout template needed on client side. Simply we would bring html

and place it inside  element on the server.

Con:
 1. As with each city we will have to place

element, this would increase bytes to be transferred.

Anyone can list more pro/con and when, how and why should be choose the former or the latter approach?

Comment: You want an API that returns JSON if you expect there to be different/varying clients that might want this data, and that will do different things with the data.

If all you anticipate doing with this `CityList` data is putting it in an HTML view in a website, I don't know why you need knockout or the API at all. Just put it in your HTML view returned to the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON or HTML: Which output can perform better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910635/json-or-html-which-output-can-perform-better)

Comment: @mmcrae: I need it through api because i am lazy loading it. Meaning i would fetch the city list only when user clicks on city drop down. I don't need it for different clients. I want it for mobile site where i feel processing from json to html might be slow.

Comment: Keep things simple for your use case. Since you don't anticipate varying clients to need that specific JSON data to do different things (you only expect to use it for this HTML display) -- it sounds like your only concern is the performance of using Knockout to layout the JSON into HTML vs returning straight up HTML. See previous comment for that discussion -- but most likely, receiving straight HTML from API will be quicker from the client's perspective.